# Why does # preface this parameter in swift

Tags: swift

```
func random(#min: CGFloat, max: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
    return random() * (max - min) + min
}
```

I am new to swift and do not know Obj-C, what is the point of # before min. This is a hard topic to search for on Google or I wouldn't be posting here. Thanks

Comment: I would recommend that you download the Apple Swift book from iTunes and read it.  This and many other questions you undoubtedly have at this point will be answered.  (And you should have a whole slew of new questions :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The hash symbol indicates that that param name should be used as an external (and local) name when you call that function. Check this link for docs: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Functions.html

For example:

```
func doSomething(#someParam: String, #someOtherParam: String){

}
```

this will use the same param name both for external and local scopes

should be called like this:

```
doSomething(someParam: "myFirstParam", someOtherParam: "mySecondParam");
```

instead of

```
doSomething("myFirstParam", "mySecondParam"); //no external param names declared in the function
```

if you want different external and local names you should declare your function like this:

```
func doSomething(myLocalParamName someParam: String, mySecondLocalParamName someOtherParam: String){
        //use local param names in here
}
```

and call the function just like before, with the external param names

As the docs indicate, the difference lies in the external and local param name. I think the example will clear that for you though.